# typedef NS_OPTIONS check like UIViewAutoresizing

Tags: ios, typedef

*A short introduction to what I want to achieve with this:*

I've a custom `UIView` where I want to make arrows visible, for example on bottom and left side.
I thought it would be possible to do this the same way as `UIViewAutoresizing` does it.

So I created a similar `typedef` for my custom view:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, Arrows) {
    ArrowNone      = 0,
    ArrowRight     = 1 << 0,
    ArrowBottom    = 1 << 1,
    ArrowLeft      = 1 << 2,
    ArrowTop       = 1 << 3
};
```

Also in my custom view header file, I added:

```
@property (nonatomic) Arrows arrows;
```

This all works and now I'm able to set the property:

`customview.arrows = (ArrowBottom | ArrowLeft);`

This returns `6`.

Now's my question, how can check if my `arrows` property contains bottom and left?
I tried:

```
if (self.arrows == ArrowLeft) {
    NSLog(@"Show arrow left");
}
```

This didn't do anything. Is there another way to check this?

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. Tried to search for it but couldn't find anything. 
Don't understand the downvote though.

Comment: @alexgray Note, it wasn't moderators that close this question.

Answer (score 36):

The right way to check your bitmask is by decoding the value using the AND (&) operator as follows:

```
Arrows a = (ArrowLeft | ArrowRight);    
if (a & ArrowBottom) {
   NSLog(@"arrow bottom code here");    
}

if (a & ArrowLeft) {
   NSLog(@"arrow left code here");    
}    

if (a & ArrowRight) {
   NSLog(@"arrow right code here");    
}

if (a & ArrowTop) {
   NSLog(@"arrow top code here");    
}
```

This will print out in the console:

```
arrow left code here
arrow right code here
```

Comment: How to check for both ArrowLeft and ArrowRight?

Comment: late to party but (a & (ArrowTop | ArrowRight)) should work

Answer (score 5):

To do a compound check you could use the following code:

```
if ((a & ArrowRight) && (a & ArrowTop)) {
       NSLog(@"arrow right and top code here");    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to check for this value is to first bitwise AND the values and 
then check for equality to the required value.

```
Arrows a = (ArrowBottom | ArrowLeft);    
if (((a & ArrowBottom) == ArrowBottom) && ((a & ArrowLeft) == ArrowLeft)) {
    // arrow bottom-left
}
```

The following reference explains why this is correct and provides other insights into enumerated types.

Reference: [checking-for-a-value-in-a-bit-mask](http://sam.dods.co/blog/2014/02/01/checking-for-a-value-in-a-bit-mask/)

Comment: But it depends on how  person is using them.